# Confused about chip antenna schematic and copper/GND from examples

Tags: rf, antenna

I want to use a TDK chip antenna (ANT016008LCS2442MA1) on my board. There are two ([design notes](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/rf/rf/antenna/design_note/dn-ant016008lcs2442ma1.pdf) [datasheet](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/rf/rf/antenna/catalog/rf_ant_ant016008lcs2442ma1_summary_en.pdf)) technical documents, but they contain little useful infromation.

My questions are:

1. `Ft-x` and `Mt` components, are these supposed to be capacitors?
2. The antenna output (Radiator electrode), is this connected to ground(/shorted to ground)? I believe it is, although I've found some schematics using similar TDK antennas and some are/aren't.
3. In the third yellow/orange/green picture, should the yellow area be copper - or copper free?
4. In the first photo, it looks like `Ft-1` and `Mt` aren't electrically connected to the tracks, but simply go over top of them?

I apologize for multiple questions at once - I'm confused about a lot. I'm not worried about optimizing range/performance at this point, just want to test it out and get it working.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Antenna chip overlapping or even connected to the GND plane on the right side looks wrong to me and the distance of Ft1 and Ft2 is not specified. I don't understand the vias in the horizontal trace of the radiator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 and 4: Ft1, Ft2, Mt are all SMT capacitors, looks like they are 0201 size. They should connect to the underlying copper trace at each end of the capacitor.

Question 2: The Radiator pad should connect to the horizontal arm of the antenna. The Feed pad should connect to the vertical trace coming up parallel to the ground plane. There are "dummy pads" in between that need not be connected. But I have to say that I think their illustration is incorrect and shows the chip antenna malpositioned. Furthermore, the illustration does not show the copper pattern design that underlies the chip; it can have considerable effect on impedance matching.

Question 3: Yes, the light yellow area is a "keepout" and should not have copper on either side of the PCB.

Overall, given the ambiguity and possible error in their drawing, you might consider another chip antenna with better documentation. But shopping is off-topic, so no specific recommendation is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I built some boards for testing with this chip, then also some around another chip antenna by Wurth Elektronic that had 1000x better documentation, so at least one will hopefully work. Thanks!